# How to join text that has been scraped from website python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website and it breaks the page up into multiple `<p>` tags. How can join the together into one string?

```
    article_wrapper = article.find('div', class_ = 'column column--full article__content')
    article_content = article_wrapper.find_all('p')

    for element in article_content:
      print(element.text)# prints article content
```

I tried to make a `data = []` and then append the element each time but that doesn't seem to work.

```
data = []
for element in article_content:
data.append(element)
print(element.text)# prints article content
print('DATA')
print(data)
```

the output I get:
[image]

I want it all in one string so that I can pass it through together instead of separate.

Comment: please show what you have tried with "data = []" - and the exact behavior.

Comment: Without more information it's hard to say, but you either need to use a more specific element than just "p," or if that's not possible, clean the individual tag responses before you append them to a list/final string.

Comment: will do ill edit the post

Comment: @goalie1998 Edit done. I think that shows where my problem is stemming from.

Comment: @Chase I added a picture to show what I tried

Comment: On an unrelated note, I read that same article today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were basically there. You printed the text of the tag, but appended the whole tag to your list. If you appended `element.text`, you would have had it. If you want it as one string instead of a list of strings, you can do this:

```py
txt = ""
for article in article_content:
    if not element.find('a'): # to filter out the extra text
        txt += article.text
```

If you want to keep each paragraph separate in a list, just change your append line to this:

```py
data = []
for element in article_content:
    if not element.find('a'): # to filter out the extra text
        data.append(element.text)
```

Comment: Thank you! The code I have that I didn't post targets just the container the article is in but what should I look up to learn how to tidy it up?

Comment: It's going to vary from site to site, but find something (tag, class, id, specific text...) in the items you want to filter out that isn't in the items you want to keep, and filter based on that. It's not always possible though. I added a filter for this specific case, but it won't work for all others.

Answer (score 1):

```
article_wrapper = article.find('div', class_ = 'column column--full article__content')
article_content = article_wrapper.find_all('p')    
data = []
for element in article_content:
    data.append(element.find_all(text=True))
print('DATA')
print(data)
```